# Is this ZF2 constant var or datatype

Tags: zend-framework2

```
public function setAlbumTable(AlbumTable $albumTable)
{
$this->albumTable = $albumTable;
return $this;
}
```

I am talking about first parameter ( it's not parameter btw) looks like datatype ? what is it ? constant ? I encounter this when trying to develop app in zend framework 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [PHP's type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php). It means that the first parameter to this function - `$albumTable` - must be an instance of the `AlbumTable` class or a class that inherits from it.

```
class Car {}

class BlueCar extends Car {}

function drive_the_car(Car $car) {}

drive_the_car(42); // error, first parameter must be an instance of Car

drive_the_car(new stdClass()); // error

drive_the_car(new Car()); // works

drive_the_car(new BlueCar()); // works
```

Answer (score 1):

The piece of code you're showing is an example of dependency injection via setter method. The setter is passed an instance of AlbumTable and assignes this instance to a class field.

Your method is passed ONLY ONE parameter: `$albumTable`.

The `AlbumTable` before the parameter is a [type hint](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) and makes sure that only a instance of AlbumTable or a deriving class can be passed to the setter.

Answer (score 0):

It forces the actual parameter ($albumTable) to be an instance of AlbumTable class. PHP will give a fatal error if anything else is passed to the function.

This is useful so you don't have to check what type of variable/object you received in order to make use of it's functions and properties.